# How to receive only one email report for multiple AWS SNS topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have several services, and each service creates an SNS topic which sends an email to me. e.g., whenever code deploy fails, I receive an email from an SNS topic, whenever codepipeline fails I receive an email from another SNS topic, whenever a specific lambda fails, I receive another SNS topic. None of the above failures is urgent, so it does not need to be taken care immediately.

How can I receive only one email report once a day for all the above failures? Maybe I should let the corresponding service trigger SQS instead of SNS and then once every day I pull all messages from SQS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you mentioned with an SQS queue subscribed to the SNS topic is probably the best way to go. You can then use a [scheduled Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) that runs once a day to poll the messages in the queue and send you an email with the aggregated information.

Comment: Hi, Tom. Thanks for your answer. I will try that!